# Build a RazorEngine template by specifying a layout in the calling code rather than the template?

Tags: razor, razorengine

Using [Antaris RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), given two strings:

- a Razor template without a layout specified

  ```
  <h1>My template</h1>
  ```
- and a layout in which it should be rendered

  ```
  <html>RenderBody()</html>
  ```

I would like to be able to parse/compile the strings and set the layout in the code performing the parsing. Something like:

```
ParseWithTemplate(templateAsString, layoutAsString, model, etc.);
```

How might I implement this `ParseWithTemplate(String, String, ...)` method?

Background: I'm building a static site generator and want a way to provide a default layout so I don't have to specify it in every single one of my many site pages. It should be possible to override the default if a `Layout = "layoutName"` is provided in the template.

Comment: FWIW, I dug deep into the Razor Engine source and decided not to use the library. The API and architecture are bit hard to follow, and make things like the above hard to customize without changing the source itself. I decided to go with the much more user-friendly, better documented, and more feature-rich (though seemingly much less well-known) Razor Machine library. (see https://github.com/jlamfers/RazorMachine and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/423141/Razor-template-engine-supporting-layouts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pre-compile the layout template, you should be able to set the Layout directly by casting the template to TemplateBase. If you later specify the Layout in the template markup, this will override the value in the code as you require when the template executes.

```
ITemplateService templateService = ...;

// Ensure layout template is cached with layoutCacheName
templateService.GetTemplate(layoutAsString, model, layoutCacheName);

ITemplate template = templateService.GetTemplate(templateAsString, model, templateCacheName);
var templateBase = template as TemplateBase;
if (templateBase != null) templateBase.Layout = layoutCacheName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I ultimately decided to switch to RazorMachine for this and many other reasons, here is a hacky fix for anyone who needs it:

```
var finalHtml = layoutHtml.Replace(@"@RenderBody()", templateHtml);
```

(Thanks to aviatrix on Github.)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the of Ryan Norbauer's answer, the easiest way to implement a layout is:

Your **_Layout.cshtml** with the typical @RenderBody()

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Your RazorEngine template **MyTemplate.cshtml**

```
@using RazorEngine.Templating
@inherits TemplateBase<myviewmodel>

<h1>Hello People</h1>
<p>@Model</p>
```

And wherever you call the RazorEngine template:

```
var TemplateFolderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates");
var template = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(TemplateFolderPath,"MyTemplate.cshtml"));
var layout = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(TemplateFolderPath, "_Layout.cshtml"));
var templateService = new TemplateService();
var templateHtml = templateService.Parse(template, myModel, null, null);
var finalHtml = layout.Replace(@"@RenderBody()", templateHtml);
```

As you can see is very simple, just place what MyTemplate.cshtml return in @RenderBody()